# DiscordJS v14: Bot not overwriting channel permissions when creating the channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So a few details I cant get the bot to overwritePermissions on the channel its creating. Also i.user.id is coming from a button interaction and when I console.log it I get the ID i expect too. and ticketNumber is just a Math.random function.

```js
const ticketChannel = await message.guild.channels.create({
                name: `ticket-${ticketNumber}`,
                type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                parent: '1118720957704585256',

                permissionsOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: everyone,
                        deny: ['ViewChannel'],  
                      },
                      {
                        allow:  ['ViewChannel', 'SendMessages', 'AttachFiles', 'ReadMessageHistory'],
                        id: i.user.id
                      },
                ],
            });
```

I have also tried ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'etc'] and [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL] nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's `permissionOverwrites`, not permissions. And you should use enums, like `PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel`, etc